# cupy AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: attributeerror, cupy

I'm trying to use the library cupy to replace numpy on some code. I'm trying to use the roots but
I get an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'. I don't have a problem with numpy

if p.dtype.kind == 'b':
375         raise NotImplementedError('boolean inputs are not supported')

Here is the fonction.

def root3(xe, ye, xp, yp, cs, c3):
#Get the roots of a polynomial

```
nu = (c3/cs)**2
A = ye**2
B = yp**2
C4 = nu-1
C3 = (-2*xp - 2*xe) * C4
C2 = nu*B - A + (xe**2 + xp**2+ 4*xe*xp) * C4
C1 = -2* nu * B * xe + 2 * A * xp + (-2* xp * xe**2 - 2*xe*xp**2) * C4
C = nu * B * xe**2 - A * xp**2 + (xe**2* xp**2)*C4
coef = [C4, C3, C2, C1, C]
R  = cp.roots(coef) 
        
return R[cp.isreal(R)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that coef has to be a cupy array as well. So, I defined `coef = cp.array([C4, C3, C2, C1, C])` and I don't get the error message anymore.

I get another one NotImplementedError: Only complex Hermitian and real symmetric 2d arrays are supported currently.